# Event listener not displaying line-through when ticking checkbox of list item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve created a function named `checkedItems`. I want the function to cross an item out each time the check box attached to it is ticked. However, nothing happens when I do so. If someone could point out where I’ve gone wrong in my code and fix it, that would be great.

```js
var elUlList = document.getElementById("ulList");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const elInput = document.getElementById("input");
const footer = document.querySelector("footer");
const message = document.getElementById("message");
const elCounter = document.getElementById("counter");

function createListItems() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  
  console.log(elements)
  
  var inputValue = elInput.value;
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  var input = document.createElement("input")
  
  input.type = "checkbox"
  
  var newText = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  
  newLi.appendChild(input);
  newLi.appendChild(newText);
  elUlList.appendChild(newLi)
}

btn.addEventListener("click", createListItems, false);
elInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn.click()
  }
})
elInput.addEventListener("mouseover", emptyField, false)

function emptyField() {
  this.value = "";
}

elUlList.addEventListener("change", checkedItems, false)

function checkedItems() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")
  var checkboxesArray = Array.from(checkboxes);
  
  console.log(checkboxes.length);
  
  if (checkboxes.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked
        ? checkboxes[i].classList.toggle("lineThrough")
        : null;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="message" class=""></div>
  <ul id="ulList"></ul>
  <button id="btn" type="button" name="button">click here to add items</button>
  <input id="input" type="text" name="" value="">
  <div id="counter" class=""></div>
  <footer></footer>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've copied and pasted your code and it still doesn't work. I mean the list items aren't being crossed out.

Comment: That was it. I works perfectly now. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer: you’re applying the `lineThrough` class to the checkbox, not its parent element, the `<li>`. The `<li>` contains the text.

The function referenced in `elUlList.addEventListener("change", checkedItems, false)` can be shortened:

```js
const checkedItems = ({target}) => {
  if(target.matches("input[type=checkbox]")){
    target.closest("li").classList.toggle("lineThrough", target.checked);
  }
}
```

[`target.closest("li")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) will always find the `<li>` that contains `target` (and is the closest parent node in the DOM tree).

[`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) accepts a second argument that will set or unset the class `"lineThrough"` based on the boolean `target.checked`.

No need to loop, because a `change` event will only be triggered when you change one specific checkbox, and you want to strike out the text in only this list item, so it’s sufficient to only target that one.

And your conditional operator was wrong: why do you *toggle* only when the checkbox is checked?

Another thing: `checkedItems` isn’t a good name for this function, as this name implies that the function returns a list of checked items or something similar, but it doesn’t. `strikeOutCheckedItem` or `toggleCheckedItem` is better; there’s also no plural, because this function only deals with one list item at a time.

Finally, make sure you actually have the CSS class defined:

```css
.lineThrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a better approach

```js
const elUlList = document.getElementById("ulList");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const elInput = document.getElementById("input");

function addItem() {
  if (elInput.value !== "") {
    const listItem = `<li>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>${elInput.value}</span>
</li>`;

    elUlList.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", listItem);

    elInput.value = "";
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addItem);
elInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    addItem();
  }
});

function isCompleted() {
  const checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll("li input");
  const tasks = document.querySelectorAll("li span");

  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxs.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
      tasks[i].classList.toggle("lineThrough");
    }
  }
}

elUlList.addEventListener("change", isCompleted);
```

```css
.lineThrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ulList"></ul>
<button id="btn" type="button" name="button">
      click here to add items
    </button>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

...

Comment: "*I think this is a better approach*" - why? You haven't explained any part of your answer, so how is the OP - and any future visitor to this page - supposed to learn anything from this? What was the problem? What did you fix? How does that fix work? Why is "this" a better approach? Better than what, and why?

Comment: I'm getting index.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: target.matches is not a function when using the following function: function strikeOutElement(target) {
  if(target.matches("input[type=checkbox]")){
    target.closest("li").classList.toggle("lineThrough", target.checked)
  }
}

Comment: @Josué Do you need any help?